# How do I upgrade my tank?

Tags: diep.io

I am playing Diep.io and I would like to know how to become another tank in Diep.io.

For example, I see an Overlord and would like to become that tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top-left corner, you can select which tank you can upgrade to. As a Basic Tank, you'll most likely see this:

[image: Basic upgrades, not including Smasher]

If you reach level 30 as a Twin, you would see a different list of upgrades.

[image: Twin upgrades]

If you press the gray Ignore button below the upgrades, the Upgrades menu will slide out. It will return again if you hover your mouse near the top-left corner. It will also automatically reappear if you reach levels 30 or 45. If it will not appear even when hovering your mouse near the corner, it is probably because you don't have any available upgrades.

Answer (score -1):

Level up by destroying squares, triangles, tanks etc. Every 15 levels you will see a bunch of options on the side. Click one to get it! Each class has different upgrades. Overseer can be obtained by upgrading to sniper at lvl. 15, then overseer at 30, then overlord. Press and hold Y to see upgrade chart. Click the pluses on the 8 bars in the lower left-hand corner to get stronger. Good luck...